# Compressing to zip file in python

Tags: python, zip, azure-blob-storage, unzip

Im grabbing pdf files and trying to compress them into zip files and then upload them to an azure blob storage container in python. The file uploads normally and looks good until i retrieve and unzip it from the database. My problem is once it is unzipped it returns the pdf file it should have but also a copy of the zip file itself. I am confused as to how this is happening. The code is as follows:

```
file_url = f"{link}"
new_response = requests.get(file_url)
if new_response.status_code == 200:
    print("got url response")
    try:
        #creates pdf file from url response to get request
        with open(f"{item_name}.pdf", "wb") as pdf_file:
            pdf_file.write(new_response.content)
            print("got pdf file")
        #creates zip file 
        with zipfile.ZipFile(f"{item_name}.zip", 'w') as zip_file:
                zip_file.writestr(f"{item_name}.pdf", new_response.content)
                print("made zip file")
                os.remove(f"{item_name}.pdf")
        #uploads zip file to db
        with open(f"{item_name}.zip", "rb") as data:
                container_client.upload_blob(name=f"{item_name}/{item_name}.zip", data=data)
                print("upload successful")
                os.remove(f"{item_name}.zip")
                uploaded_items += 1
       container_client.upload_blob(name=f"{item_name}/{item_name} metadata", data=json.dumps(result))
    except Exception as e:
        print('There was an error uploading the file: ')
        print(e)
        missed_items += 1
        continue
```

I've tried changing file directories but that didn't work

Answer (score 0):

It seems that you are creating a zip file inside another zip file by using the **writestr** method of the **zipfile** module. This method writes raw data represented by bytes into an archive, and the first argument is the name of the file that the archive will contain. In your code, you are passing the same name for both the zip file and the pdf file, which causes the zip file to be nested inside itself.

To avoid this, you should either use a different name for the zip file and the pdf file, or use the **write** method instead of the **writestr** method. The **write** method takes a filename as an argument and adds the contents of that file to the archive. For example:

```py
#creates zip file 
with zipfile.ZipFile(f"{item_name}.zip", 'w') as zip_file:
        # use write method instead of writestr
        zip_file.write(f"{item_name}.pdf")
        print("made zip file")
        os.remove(f"{item_name}.pdf")
```

Check this out:
https://docs.python.org/3/library/zipfile.html#zipfile.ZipFile.write

Comment: So i did this and i honestly can't tell if it works. If i double click on the zip file within the blob container itll give me both the zip file and its contents but if i right click and select download on the zip file it'll just give me the zip file. If i unzip that downloaded file it gives me just the pdf file it contains. So i guess this may be a weird quirk with azure storage explorer?

Comment: I'm not sure why that happens, but it seems like the zip file is correctly created and uploaded to the blob container. Maybe it's a bug or a feature of the Azure Storage Explorer that shows the zip file inside itself when you double click on it. As long as you can download and unzip the file and get the pdf file you want, I think you are good to go.